# type() function with an integer?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been working on a code,and a part of it is giving me a lot of trouble. This is it.

```
import math
number=raw_input("Enter the number you wish to find its square root: ")
word=number
if type(word)==type(int):
    print sqrt(word)
```

In IDLE, whenever I type a number, nothing is printed. I checked for syntax errors and indentation in the editor and I fixed all of them.

Comment: Just something to think: What did you expect `word=number` to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were looking for `isinstance()`:

```
if isinstance(word, int):
```

But that won't work, because `raw_input()` returns a *string*. You perhaps need exception handling instead:

```
try:
    word = int(word)
except ValueError:
    print 'not a number!'
else:
    print sqrt(word)
```

For your specific mistake, `type(word) is int` might have worked as well, but that is not very pythonic. `type(int)` returns the type of the `int` type, which is `<type 'type'>`:

```
>>> type(42)
<type 'int'>
>>> type(42) is int
True
>>> type(int)
<type 'type'>
>>> type(int) is type
True
```

Answer (score 1):

raw_input returns a string.
You need to convert the input to an number

```
in_string = raw_input("...")
try:
    number = float(in_string)
    print math.sqrt(number)
except ValueError as e:
    print "Sorry, {} is not a number".format(in_string)
```